# Nvidia Optimus error

Tags: nvidia-prime

I have a question =)
After installing Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 15.10 I have this error on my boot screen [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoiDT.jpg)
How can I fix it?

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0647
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GeForce 710M
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: nvidia-prime is not a driver, it is NVIDIA Optimus (to switch between internal and dedicated graphics) support - please edit your question with the output from this command : lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the NVIDIA drivers - but first remove the NVIDIA software you have installed.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot ... install the **NVIDIA drivers 352** from the official Ubuntu repositories.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

NVIDIA X Server Settings - **PRIME Profiles** : switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics.

Comment: Thanks but i still have a issue with error what is shown on my question.

Comment: @MartinsRudavs : Please check whether you have to enable switchable mode or NVIDIA graphics in BIOS. If you still get an error after switching the mode or enabling the card, please report back. :)

Comment: I checked.I don't have option to switch in bios

Comment: @MartinsRudavs : What is the exact model name of your Acer notebook ?

Comment: acer aspire v3 571g

Comment: @MartinsRudavs : Does the Ubuntu desktop work properly without issues regardless this message ?

Comment: works perfectly but after installing nvidia drivers that error showing but otherwise everything works perfectly

Comment: @MartinsRudavs Good to hear this - you then can just ignore the message. Acer notebooks are known to sometimes having some compatibility issues, especially BIOS related things - enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)